# How to solve the error in xy coords: 'x' and 'y' differ in length

Tags: r

I'm trying to knit my file into a pdf, however it keeps saying my x and y lengths differ. I checked in the console, it showed that the lengths are the same (100). I'm not sure what else I can do to fix it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzHlg.png)

Comment: Are there any missing values? Is `sum(is.na(datafinal$CLJ))` or `sum(is.na(datafinal$"sum of accuracy"))` greater than 0?

Comment: @dcarlson I just checked again, and there aren't any missing values.

Comment: What is `length(datafinal$CLJ)` and `length(datafinal$"sum of accuracy")`? If they agree, it will not be possible to provide further assistance without a reproducible example.